# How to use parent page javascript file in child jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp

my parent jsp contains two div..

```
<html>
<script src="a.js"/>
<body>
<div id="child1"></div>
<div id="child2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my child page is

```
<html>
<body>
child_1
</body>
</html>
```

using ajax call i am loading child page into my parent div and want to use the same js file in child page loaded by parent page by referring it using any method and not by manually including it on child page,So please anyone help me with this i am in big trouble because of this.

Comment: Create header file and refactor your project. Example here:  http://wiki4.caucho.com/Java_EE_Servlet_tutorial_:_Using_JSPs_to_create_header,_footer_area,_formatting,_and_basic_CSS_for_bookstore

Comment: But i will have to add this header to child page which i dont want.

Comment: But i will have to add this header to child page which i dont want. Actually my template is already made and when i will use this template it will add one whole page onto the parents page so i am not using template on child page but problem with this approach is i am not able to add script file on child page because my js file name is dynamic and which will be resolved only in parent jsp and not in child. SO is there any way to use the js link already prepared in parent page?

Comment: Add parameter with script link in ajax call then in child page get from request and load as script.

Comment: i din get how to do it Can u plse elaborate..

Comment: Show your ajax call.

Comment: $.get('/home', function(){ $('#child1').html(data);});

Answer (score 0):

In ajax call:

```
$.get('/home',
    {script:'resolvedJSLink'},
    function(){$('#child1').html(data);}
);
```

And in child1.jsp:

```
<html>
    <script src='<%= request.getParameter("script") %>'/>
    <body>
        child_1
    </body>
</html>
```

Maybe another solution for this case is load script dynamically: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: I this approach i need resolved link of js file but the file link is resolved at run time in parent jsp.  Can i get name of loaded js file in parent?

Comment: Yes, because you use it in parent jsp. You must replace 'resolvedJSLink' with your method of resolving js file if you want get at runtime of processing parent file. Or get this name on client side using jQuery and selector ie. $('script').attr('src').

Comment: It almost solved my problem but $('script').attr('src') gives me first loaded javascript file name what about other script files. For eg if i want to get the name of 2nd js file then how can i get that?

Comment: You can create array with src values like this: `var src = [];
$('script').each(function () {
  src.push($(this).attr('src')); 
});`